# unique value from the list

Tags: excel, vba, unique

Item no
2
4
2
7
5
6

`Range("A9").Select ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = _ "=UNIQUE('1.Technical Compliance'!R[-2]C[4]:R[45]C[4])"`

The result from above VBA is:

Item no
2
4
5
6
7
0

From the result, how to avoid "0" value at last row

Answer (score 2):

### Zeros With UNIQUE

**Using TOCOL (Great!)**

- As suggested by JvdV, using `TOCOL` is by far superior (and more efficient).

```
Range("A9").Formula2R1C1 = _
    "=TOCOL(UNIQUE('1.Technical Compliance'!R[-2]C[4]:R[45]C[4]),1)"
```

- It will ignore the empty cells (that are selling themselves as cells containing zeros).
- It will additionally (with the 2nd parameter set to 3), enable the formula not to fail if there are error values in the data.
- It will not ignore blank cells that are not empty.

**Using LET and FILTER (Bad!)**

- If you want to exclude the zero produced by empty cells, use the following:

```
Range("A9").Formula2R1C1 = _
    "=LET(data,'1.Technical Compliance'!R[-2]C[4]:R[45]C[4]," _
    & "UNIQUE(FILTER(data,data<>"""")))"
```

- It will fail if there are error values in the data.
- It will additionally ignore blank cells that are not empty.
- If there are zeros in the data, a zero will be contained in the list.
- If you don't want to show a zero at all, replace `""""` with `0`.

Comment: I guess one could nest TOCOL() too and avoid LET() and FILTER().

Comment: @JvdV Thanks for a valuable lesson. Hopefully I will memorize it once and for all.